# RPI not recieving I2C master's messages

Tags: i2c, c++

Im trying to use a RPI3B+ to emulate a WiiMotion Plus, So i have it set up as a slave using `pigpio` and connected to a wiimote.

- **Expected outcome**: The wiimote will try to read from register 0xfe and write an activation byte to it. If the wiimotion plus is there, it will become activated and start reporting gyro data
- **Current outcome**: `bscXfer()` is not reporting any messages

Since I've tested this on an arduino nano with the same setup and gotten correct results, i know its the fault of the raspberry pi. I currently have 4 files in my setup, 3 of which handle logic, the first one handling i2c interactions. I know the logic is correct, as i took it from [dolphin](https://github.com/dolphin-emu/dolphin). And the i2c *should* be correct, as i took it from [this repo](https://github.com/rameyjm7/rpi_i2c_slave).

However it still does not work, instead giving me this output when i run it, and halting.

```
Initialized GPIOs
Opened slave
```

Since this entire file is devoted to communicating over i2c, im unaware why its halting where it does, and my situation is so specific i doubt it could be reproduced, i should be able to go away with an MRE.

```
#include "MotionPlus.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <pigpio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define MAX_BYTES 16
#define ACTIVE_ADDR 0x52
#define SLEEP 1000    

void runSlave(int);
bool UpdateAddress();
int getControlBits(int, bool);

std::uint8_t slave_addr = 0x53;
WiimoteEmu::MotionPlus motion_plus;
bsc_xfer_t xfer;

int main() {
    gpioInitialise();
    std::cout << "Initialized GPIOs\n";

    // Resets all state.
    motion_plus.Reset();

    // Set I2C slave Address to slave_addr
    xfer.control = getControlBits(slave_addr, true);
    runSlave(bscXfer(&xfer));

    // FYI: If you do want to implement passthrough extensions you might have to
    // change some stuff inside MotionPlus.cpp. Dolphin was a bit different in
    // that area because it does not have to rely on the time it takes to talk on
    // a real i2c bus.
}

inline bool UpdateAddress() {
    if (motion_plus.ReadDeviceDetectPin() && slave_addr != ACTIVE_ADDR) {
        // Close old device
        xfer.control = getControlBits(slave_addr, false); // To avoid conflicts when restarting
        bscXfer(&xfer);

        std::cout << "Activating\n";
        slave_addr = ACTIVE_ADDR;

        // Set I2C slave Address to 0x52
        xfer.control = getControlBits(slave_addr, true);
        runSlave(bscXfer(&xfer));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void runSlave(int status) {
    if (status >= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Opened slave\n";
        xfer.rxCnt = 0;
        while (UpdateAddress()) {
            bscXfer(&xfer);
            usleep(SLEEP);

            // this will be I2C read function, return the register number rxBuf[0]
            if (xfer.rxCnt == 1) {
                int reg = xfer.rxBuf[0];

                std::printf("# Received read request to register 0x%02x\n", reg);
                xfer.txCnt = motion_plus.BusRead(slave_addr, reg, MAX_BYTES, (std::uint8_t*)xfer.txBuf);
                int r = bscXfer(&xfer);

                std::printf("# Transfer returned %d\n", r);
            }
            else if (xfer.rxCnt > 1) {
                int reg = xfer.rxBuf[0];
                int count = xfer.rxCnt - 1;

                std::printf("# Writing %d bytes to register %d\n", count, reg);
                motion_plus.BusWrite(slave_addr, reg, count, (std::uint8_t*)xfer.rxBuf + 1);
            }

            xfer.rxCnt = 0;
            xfer.txCnt = 0;
            memset(xfer.rxBuf, '\0', sizeof(char) * BSC_FIFO_SIZE);
            memset(xfer.txBuf, '\0', sizeof(char) * BSC_FIFO_SIZE);


            // The MotionPlus object expects to have its Update function called
            // UPDATE_FREQ times a second (200hz). It has some internal "timers".
            motion_plus.Update();
        }
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Failed to open slave!!!\n";

    xfer.control = getControlBits(slave_addr, false);
    bscXfer(&xfer);
    std::cout << "Closed slave.\n";

    gpioTerminate();
    std::cout << "Terminated GPIOs.\n";
}

int getControlBits(int address /* max 127 */, bool open) {
    int flags;
    if (open)
        flags = /*RE:*/ (1 << 9) | /*TE:*/ (1 << 8) | /*I2:*/ (1 << 2) | /*EN:*/ (1 << 0);
    else // Close/Abort
        flags = /*BK:*/ (1 << 7) | /*I2:*/ (0 << 2) | /*EN:*/ (0 << 0);

    return (address << 16 /*= to the start of significant bits*/) | flags;
}
```

Comment: yes correct `xfer.rxCnt` is always less than 1, its not receiving the messages despite the fact they *are* being sent.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, didn't read the question properly :p